# Input & Output Impedances of Common Emitter BJT Amplifier

Tags: bjt, impedance, common-emitter

I want to study about *"finding Input & Output Impedances of Common Emitter BJT Amplifier"*

However, I could not find a decent source & document about it.

Could someone supply me with some documents for that?

Comment: Actually, my academician told us to work on our own. We use Razavi's microelectronics textbook but inside it, that topic covered not clearly for self-working. That is why I just want to learn about input and output impedances of the common emitter, please?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please visit the [tour] page if you have not already done so. Please include in the question, what you already know about calculating input and output impedances and what you have already tried for common emitter configuration. Please also add a clear, labelled circuit diagram.

Comment: Okay, ı will add it. Thank you. Yet, I am so new in this sub-topic and I could not find enough resources from google and youtube. I am sorry but I am at the point that even I don't have a question for this particular topic.

Comment: Ah, this is great, let me check them, please. Thank you

Comment: Recommendations are off topic here. So, in the current form, your question may get closed.

Comment: Thank you so much for this suggestion, now I'm searching up inside that book to study about them. Could you tell me please, in the next time for the suggestions where should I ask my question please rather than here if it is off-topic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [a link](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/input-impedance-of-an-amplifier.html)! with the equations. For more information, I would recommend the book "Electronic Devices and Circuit Theory" by Robert L. Boylestad and Louis Nashelsky

Comment: You are the best, thank you so much for that...